# Confidence Interval for ratio Between Two Means

Tags: r, confidence-interval, two-sample

I am trying to do something similar to what it is explained in [this tutorial](http://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/MPH-Modules/BS/BS704_Confidence_Intervals/BS704_Confidence_Intervals5.html). The difference is that I want to obtain a 95% CI for the **ratio** between the means of two populations. In few words, I am interested in computing 95%CI of the ratio instead of the difference (subtraction) because I am comparing two populations in multiple conditions, with different scales (see below):

I am using R for all my calculations and I will use `dput` to input the example dataframes.

Considering the following data frame (the variable `avg_fluorescence_minus_background` is the mean value of 8 measures, for both `VL` and `NEHC`):

```
structure(list(peptide_factor = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("ABC", "Background", "EpQ_11"), class = "factor"), 
    conc_factor = c("0.29 ", "0.29 ", "0.57 ", "0.57 ", "1.15 ", 
    "1.15 ", "2.3 ", "2.3 "), serum_factor = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("NEHC", "VL"), class = "factor"), 
    avg_fluorescence_minus_background = c(4129.724609375, 6536.05179268973, 
    10811.8256835938, 15954.4743303571, 25070.1661376953, 45507.1811523438, 
    48319.0120849609, 49874.4587751116)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), vars = c("conc_factor", 
"serum_factor"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(conc_factor = c("0.29 ", 
"0.29 ", "0.57 ", "0.57 ", "1.15 ", "1.15 ", "2.3 ", "2.3 "), 
    serum_factor = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("NEHC", "VL"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), vars = c("conc_factor", "serum_factor"), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("conc_factor", 
"serum_factor")), .Names = c("peptide_factor", "conc_factor", 
"serum_factor", "avg_fluorescence_minus_background"))
```

Considering now that I am grouping by the variables `peptide_factor` and `conc_factor`, I have computed the ratio between the groups `VL` and `NEHC`, as shown in the following data frame:

```
structure(list(peptide_factor = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("ABC", "Background", "EpQ_11"), class = "factor"), 
    conc_factor = c("0.29 ", "0.29 ", "0.57 ", "0.57 ", "1.15 ", 
    "1.15 ", "2.3 ", "2.3 "), serum_factor = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("NEHC", "VL"), class = "factor"), 
    avg_fluorescence_minus_background = c(4129.724609375, 6536.05179268973, 
    10811.8256835938, 15954.4743303571, 25070.1661376953, 45507.1811523438, 
    48319.0120849609, 49874.4587751116), difference_background = c(1, 
    1.5826846608251, 1, 1.47565034780084, 1, 1.81519264381417, 
    1, 1.03219119396348)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), vars = c("peptide_factor", 
"conc_factor"), labels = structure(list(peptide_factor = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("ABC", "Background", "EpQ_11"), class = "factor"), 
    conc_factor = c("0.29 ", "0.57 ", "1.15 ", "2.3 ")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), vars = c("peptide_factor", "conc_factor"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
    conc_factor = c("0.29 ", "0.29 ", "0.57 ", "0.57 ", "1.15 ", 
    "1.15 ", "2.3 ", "2.3 "), serum_factor = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("NEHC", "VL"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), vars = c("conc_factor", "serum_factor"), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("conc_factor", 
"serum_factor")), .Names = c("peptide_factor", "conc_factor")), indices = list(
    0:1, 2:3, 4:5, 6:7), drop = TRUE, group_sizes = c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), biggest_group_size = 2L, .Names = c("peptide_factor", 
"conc_factor", "serum_factor", "avg_fluorescence_minus_background", 
"difference_background"))
```

I am interested in the ratio between `VL/NEHC` (and not in the difference) because, as we can see, the scale varies according to `conc_factor`. Roughly speaking, I want to normalise my data.

Is there a way to compute the confidence intervals for the **ratio** between Two Means, instead of the Confidence Interval for a **Difference** Between Two Means .

Comment: A more standard term for what you ask is "ratio" or "proportion" (rather than "division").  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=ratio+delta+confidence for closely related questions.

Comment: Bayesian statistic is so convenient ! :-)